# how to make a simple star notation in symfony 3

Tags: javascript, symfony, rating-system

Good evening, I try to allow patients to note the doctors they consulted, so that after the search for doctors, the most noticeable appear first. But here I do not know how to do it too much. And in the first place I added a voting attribute to my entity.

**Entity**

```
  class Medecin
 {
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="sexe", type="string", length=40)
 */
public $sexe;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="note", type="integer")
 */
private $note = 0;
```

}

and here is my twig file where I display the doctor's data with the stars as well:

**Twig**

```
 <span class="rating">
                                {% for i in 1..5 %}
                                    <i class="icon_star {{ medecin.note >= (i * 20) ? 'voted' : ''}}"></i>
                                {% endfor %}
                        | <small>  <strong>{{ medecin.note }}</strong></small>
                    </span>
```

**CSS**

```css
.rating i {
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
}
.rating i.voted {
  color: #FFC107;
}
.rating small {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}
.rating small a {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

My problem is that when I fly over the stars no action happens. And then how to record the vote, when the patient clicks on the number of votes, and that his vote is recorded to the affiliated doctor ?
Thanks

Comment: 1) a doctor can receive many ratings from many users, so you need to somehow save all those ratings in a seprate db table linked to doctro_id. 2) Then display average rating for each doctor 3) ratings should have aditional input fields in case a user (that has not yet rated the current doctor) whishes to rate her

Answer (score 0):

Please code in English, not french nor Dutch, or Chinese. Choose English for your code base.

You need to have a Rating entity:

**Doctor**

```
class Doctor
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=“Rating”, mappedBy=“doctor”)
     */
    protected $ratings;

    // ...
}
```

**Rating**

```
class Rating
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type=“integer”, name=“value”)
     */
    protected $value;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=“Doctor”, inversedBy=“ratings”)
     */
    protected $doctor;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=“Patient”, inversedBy=“ratings”)
     */
    protected $patient;

    // ...
}
```

**Patient**

```
class Patient
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=“Rating”, mappedBy=“patient”, cascade={“persist”, “remove”})
     */
    protected $ratings;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Trix sorry for my late. I applied your recommendations, And now how to save the vote, when the patient clicks on the number of votes. And I would like to know, it's not anyone who has to click on the stars to vote, it has to be a patient ? Thanks

Comment: please ask separate questions for separate things to help questions and answers more useful to other users. I can not understand your English well, but if you have problem with Patient, replace it with User. you may share your Domain Model if you have detailed questions about that

Comment: Sorry @Trix for my English. But you said I'll need the Rating entity. I did it and now what's next. Knowing that the goal is to allow a patient to note a doctor. Please help me.Thanks

Comment: you should put your RatingType form in doctor profile and process it in your DoctorController